# cuda matrix multiplication by columns

Tags: cuda, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to do matrix multiplication in cuda.  My implementation is different from the cuda example.

The cuda example (from the cuda samples) performs matrix multiplication by multiplying each value in the row of the first matrix by each value in the column of the second matrix, then summing the products and storing it in an output vector at the index of the row from the first matrix.

My implementation multiplies each value in the column of the first matrix by the single value of the row of the second matrix, where the row index = column index.  It then has an output vector in global memory that has each of its indices updated.

The cuda example implementation can have a single thread update each index in the output vector, whereas my implementation can have multiple threads updating each index.

The results that I get show only some of the values.  For example, if I had it do 4 iterations of updates, it would only do 2 or 1.

I think that the threads might be interfering with each other since they're all trying to write to the same indices of the vector in global memory.  So maybe, while one thread is writing to an index, the other might not be able to insert its value and update the index?

Just wondering if this assessment makes sense.

For example.  To multiply the following two matrices:

```
[3 0 0 2         [1       [a
 3 0 0 2    x     2   =    b
 3 0 0 0          3        c
 0 1 1 0]         4]       d]
```

The Cuda sample does matrix multiplication in the following way using 4 threads where a,b,c,d are stored in global memory:

```
Thread 0:   3*1 + 0*2 + 0*3 + 2*4 = a
Thread 1:   3*1 + 0*2 + 0*3 + 2*4 = b
Thread 2:   3*1 + 0*2 + 0*3 + 0*4 = c
Thread 3:   0*1 + 1*2 + 1*3 + 0*4 = d
```

My implementation looks like this:

```
a = b = c = d = 0

Thread 0:
3*1 += a
3*1 += b
3*1 += c
0*1 += d

Thread 1:
0*2 += a
0*2 += b
0*2 += c
1*2 += d

Thread 2:
0*3 += a
0*3 += b
0*3 += c
1*3 += d

Thread 3:
2*4 += a
2*4 += b
0*4 += c
0*4 += d
```

So at one time all four threads could be trying to update one of the indices.

Comment: Some code for your kernel would probably help.  And I can't say I understand your description completely.  But if you have multiple threads updating a given output point, then you probably want to think about using [atomics](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) to avoid interference between threads.

Comment: So you are basically scaling columns of one matrix by the diagonal entries of another? It isn't immediately obvious why you would need to have multiple threads updating a single output entry. Won't each output entry be independent of anything other than its own value and the constant diagonal entry of the second matrix?

Comment: Sorry for the vague description.  I updated the question to help describe the problem.  My concern is that the threads are interfering with each other when they try to update the output vector.  I'll take a look at atomics and see what that is about.  Thanks for the responses!

Comment: The end result is the same matrix multiplication. Why are you trying to re-invent the wheel ?

Comment: It is just convenient for me because of the way my data is stored.  The values are extracted from an adjacency list so the matrix is actually being represented with a struct and an array.  The struct is indexed based on columns.  If I want to find a row, I'd have to use a for loop to search for the row I want inside one of the columns... So it is inefficient to perform matrix computations the traditional way because I cant access rows directly from my data structure.

Comment: I implemented atomicAdd and it did the trick.  Thanks Robert!

Comment: Would you mind posting what you did as an answer, then wait a day and then accept your answer.  Then we can call this question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix this issue, I used **atomicAdd** to do the **+=** operation.  When a thread performs the operation **3*1 += a** (for example), it does three things.

> 1. It gets the previous value of **a**
> 2. It updates the value by doing **3*1 +** previous value of **a**
> 3. It then stores the new value into **a**

By using [atomicAdd](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) it guarantees that these operations can occur by the thread without interruption from other threads.  If **atomicAdd** is not used, thread0 could get the previous value of **a** and while thread0 is updating the value, thread1 could get the previous value of **a** and perform its own update.  In this way a **+=** operation would not occur because the threads aren't able to finish their operations.

If **a += 3*1** is used instead of **atomicAdd(&a, 3*1)**, then it is possible for thread1 to interfere and change the value of thread0 before thread0 finishes what it's doing.  It creates a race condition.

**atomicAdd** is a **+=** operation.  You would use the following code to perform the operation:

```
__global__ void kernel(){    
int a = 0;   
atomicAdd(&a, 3*1);  //is the same as a += 3*1
}
```